# Xamarin Show Item Template Get Break Mode

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm creating an app, with button on a contentPage, and when i click that button, it will move to new contentPage. But it got some problems.
I use sqlite database 
the connection is fine.

this is model class

```
public class entries
{
    public entries()
    {

    }

    public entries(string word)
    {
        this.word = word;
    }
    public entries(string word, string wordtype, string definition)
    {
        this.word = word;
        this.type = wordtype;
        this.defn = definition;
    }   
    public string word
    { get; set; }

    public string type
    { get; set; }

    public string sdex { get; set; }
    public int wlen { get; set; }

    public string defn
    { get; set; }


}
```

Button in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public string word;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



   //this is the button
    async void AllWordButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new AllWordPage());


    }
```

}

this is AllWordPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class OrtherAppPage : ContentPage
{
    private SQLiteConnection conn;
    public entries entry;
    public OrtherAppPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        conn = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
        var data = (from word in conn.Table<entries>() select word);
        DataList.ItemsSource = data;
    }

}
```

this is AllWordPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Label Text="This is Other App Page" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="DataList">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Word}"></TextCell>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

When i click the button. it get this notification: 
Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).

How can i show this problem. Please Help. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems in the shared code:

1. `ContentPage` can contain only one child. `AllWordPage.xaml` contains 2 `StackLayouts`. This will throw an exception in runtime.
2. According to [C# naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces) `entries` should be named `Entries`.
3. Use [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm).
4. `Entries` should be decorated with `Table("Entries")` attribute.
5. Each table should contain an `Id` column, so it will be possible to identify a single row. There are few additional columns that might be helpful like `CreatedAt`, `DeletedAt`, `RowVersion` and etc.
6. `SQLiteConnection` should be disposed.
7. Use `async` methods not to block the UI thread - `(from word in conn.Table<entries>() select word)` -> `conn.Table<entries>().ToListAsync()`
8. Consider using `EntityFramework`.

P.S.: [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm) contains good code examples and explanations. Start there.